# Different page parameters inside query

Tags: meta-query

I get with that code some pictures from different pages they have a special parent page.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'page', 
        'post_parent__in' => array(376, 379), 
        'orderby'         => 'title', 
        'order'           => ASC,  
        'posts_per_page'  => 9999
    )
);
```

But now i want that the code not only look for parent pages but also for single pages. Is it possible to combine `post_parent__in` & `post__in`?

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'page', 
        'post_parent__in' => array(376, 379),
        'post__in'        => array(1148),
        'orderby'         => 'title', 
        'order'           => ASC,  
        'posts_per_page'  => 9999
    )
);
```

If i use the second code it shows me nothing. It should look for images they are have a parent page or a specific page id.

Thx for your Help

Shortcode code:

```
function galerie_klassisch_wohnen() { 

$query = new WP_Query( 
    array(
        'post_type'       => 'page', 
        'post_parent__in' => array(376, 379, 382),
        'orderby'         => 'title', 
        'order'           => ASC,  
        'posts_per_page'  => 9999
    )
);
   if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
         $return_string .= '<div class="dynamische-galerie"><div class="col-3"><div class="dynamische-galerie-wrapper"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array(285,200) ).'</a><div class="dynamische-galerie-caption"><a href="'.get_permalink().'"><b>'.get_the_title().'</b><br>'.number_format(get_field( 'nettogrundflaeche' ),2,',','.').'<span>&nbsp;m²</span></a></div></div></div></div>';
      endwhile;
      return $return_string;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
add_shortcode( 'galerie_klassisch_wohnen', 'galerie_klassisch_wohnen' );
```

Answer (score 2):

NO, you cannot combine `post_in` and `post_not_in` in the same query. Both are mutually exclusive, So it is impossible for mutually exclusive events to occur at the same time.

Comment: I use this code inside a shortcode, can i combine perhaps different loops to get this to work. I post the complete code above.

Comment: -1 It's `post_parent__in` and `post__in`, which are not mutually exclusive.